# SQL Collapse Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands, distinct-values

I am trying to collapse data that is in a sequence sorted by date. While grouping on the person and the type.

The data is stored in an SQL server and looks like the following -

```
seq  person  date                 type
---  ------  -------------------  ----
1    1       2018-02-10 08:00:00  1
2    1       2018-02-11 08:00:00  1
3    1       2018-02-12 08:00:00  1
4    1       2018-02-14 16:00:00  1
5    1       2018-02-15 16:00:00  1
6    1       2018-02-16 16:00:00  1
7    1       2018-02-20 08:00:00  2
8    1       2018-02-21 08:00:00  2
9    1       2018-02-22 08:00:00  2
10   1       2018-02-23 08:00:00  1
11   1       2018-02-24 08:00:00  1
12   1       2018-02-25 08:00:00  2
13   2       2018-02-10 08:00:00  1
14   2       2018-02-11 08:00:00  1
15   2       2018-02-12 08:00:00  1
16   2       2018-02-14 16:00:00  3
17   2       2018-02-15 16:00:00  3
18   2       2018-02-16 16:00:00  3
```

This data set contains about 1.2 million records that resemble the above.

The result that I would like to get from this would be -

```
person  start                type
------  -------------------  ----
1       2018-02-10 08:00:00  1
1       2018-02-20 08:00:00  2
1       2018-02-23 08:00:00  1
1       2018-02-25 08:00:00  2
2       2018-02-10 08:00:00  1
2       2018-02-14 16:00:00  3
```

I have the data in the first format by running the following query -

```
select 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS seq 
  person, 
  date, 
  type, 
from table
group by person, date, type
```

I am just not sure how to keep the minimum date with the other distinct values from person and type.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: I have added the tag sql-server. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem so, you can use differences of `row_number()` & use them in grouping :

```
select person, min(date) as start, type
from (select *, 
              row_number() over (partition by person order by seq) seq1,
              row_number() over (partition by person, type order by seq) seq2
      from table
     ) t
group by person, type, (seq1 - seq2)
order by person, start;
```

Comment: I am seeing a couple of weird things with this query.

In one example: 2018-12-30 06:30:00 has a type of 6 but the results show the type as a 1.

I am also seeing that a different record is created when the times are different so these records follow one another -
    1373  2009-02-24 08:00:00  1
    1373  2009-03-10 18:00:00  1

Comment: @stats. . . Might be need `type` also in `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution using the difference of row numbers is:

```
select person, type, min(date) as start
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by person order by seq) as seqnum_p,
             row_number() over (partition by person, type order by seq) as seqnum_pt
      from t
     ) t
group by person, type, (seqnum_p - seqnum_pt)
order by person, start;
```

`type` needs to be included in the `GROUP BY`.